# How to clear notification after reading it from IOS notification center one by one?

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, push

In IOS app, is there any options to clear a single notification or marked it as read after tapping on it?
My belief is that Apple does not provide this feature. They only provide to clear all the notifications at a time.
I searched a lot but didn't find any solution. Though I have found clearing one notification at a time in some apps (ex. Gmail).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the number in this property

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber
```

For example to decrease it by one

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber -= 1;
```

To set it to a specific value

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5;
```

Comment: But does it clear that particular notification from the notification center after tapping on it?

Comment: Oh, no it just decreases the badge number

Comment: i dont think you can do that in anyway

Comment: You must be able to do this because LinkedIn does it while Instagram doesn't. If you get a push from LinkedIn and then view it it gets cleared from notification Center. But the same doesn't happen with Imstagram.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107957/how-to-clear-a-single-notification-from-a-list-of-notifications-on-clicking

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this would work with push notifications, but you can cancel individual local notifications like this:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];`

You can get a reference to the notification that was tapped by the App Delegate `application:DidReceiveLocalNotification` method.